# Training lexicalized PCFG using NLTK

Tags: nlp, nltk

I was wondering if it is possible to train (on tree bank) and use lexicalized PCFG using NLTK toolkit? Does it support it or is there some way around to do it easily?
Is there any other tool to do it?

Comment: Isn't [the Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) stack exechange site should be a better place to ask such questions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the following?:

- http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.grammar-module.html
- http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch08-extras.html

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a starting point...

- [projective_prob_parse_demo](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/parse/projectivedependencyparser.html#projective_prob_parse_demo)

This example uses a 'tree bank' defined in [conll_data2](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/master/nltk/parse/dependencygraph.py) (scroll down to line 428).